# react native - image not showing properly

Tags: react-native, react-native-image

I'm using the normal image tag to display server image but some images are showing properly and some are not.

- I'm using react-native to for android application
- I have used react-native-responsive-dimensions for image sizing
  relative to screen size.
- Passed image URL through a state.

```html
<View>
   <Image 
     style={{borderWidth:1,
     width: responsiveWidth(100),
     height: responsiveHeight(50),
     resizeMode:'contain'}} 
     source = {{ uri:this.state.productimage}}/>
</View>
```

[image: this is how my product image is looking like]

Comment: for remote images width and height needs to be provided.

Comment: Can you please share the code? so that we will able to understand how multiple images you have used and can we know the platform for which issue replicating(i.e.android or ios)?

Comment: borderWidth was causing the issue. after removing borderWidth from CSS of an image tag image is showing properly. sorry and thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to display your server image in grid then may be this works for you

```js
<Image source={{uri:"http://pngimg.com/uploads/google/google_PNG19632.png"}} style={{height:null,width:null,flex:0.5,resizeMode:'contain'}}  />
```

or change resizeMode:'cover'

Comment: `resizeMode:'contain' ` saved me :)

Answer (score 0):

provide height-width in style of image tag

```html
<Image 
source = {{ uri:"http://pngimg.com/uploads/google/google_PNG19632.png" }} 
style = {{ height:100, width:100 }}/>
```

Comment: my image is displaying but not proper.